# PHP if statement with multiple "not equal to or"

Tags: php, variables, if-statement

So I have this block of PHP code:

```
<?php
    if ("$page_id" !== '2' || "$page_id" !== '8'){
        $path = './images/'; // Only if $page_id !== '2 || 8'
    } else if ("$page_id" == '5' || "$page_id" == '6' || "$page_id" == '7') {
        $path = '../images/'; // Only if $page_id == '5-7'
    } else {
        $path = '/images/'; // For everything else
    }
?>
```

But it seems to use only (`$path = './images/';`). What is going wrong?

Comment: $page !== 2 || $page !== 8 is going to satisfy all the conditions as there is an OR condition. Please correct that

Comment: @Charlie that depends on what type `$page_id` is.

Comment: Apart from the question itself, it is in my opinion better to first cast $page_id to an integer, and the compare with integer values.
Shorter code, easier maintenance.

Comment: @CharlieS because they don't know what type `$page_id` will be and putting it in quotes is a lazy way of doing `(string)$page_id` to ensure it's a type you can work with.

Comment: if `$page_id` is an integer then it is not equals to `'2'` or `'8'` because `'2'` and `'8'` are strings. Your condition is build with type comparison.

Comment: The question is silly because even fixing the or condition on the first line still exposes dodgy logic, since anything that's NOT 2 or 8 covers the situation of 5, 6 and 7 getting through, so the middle condition will still never be called.

Comment: You need to clear the logic first. There are big flaw in logic and is not at all clear

Comment: @scragar I see what you mean, and I deleted my comment. Still, using `===` without knowing what type you're comparing against is probably not the best way to go about it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
if ("$page_id" !== '2' || "$page_id" !== '8')
```

Something is always unequal to either '2' or '8', so I expect you meant this to be:

```
if ("$page_id" !== '2' && "$page_id" !== '8')
```

Or, to make it more clear (more in line with the `else` conditions at least):

```
if (! ("$page_id" == '2' || "$page_id" == '8') )
```

Note, that `==` is not strict, while `!==` is. The proper counterpart would be `===`, so if you prefer strict comparisons, the entire statement would become:

```
if (!("$page_id" === '2' || "$page_id" === '8')){
    $path = './images/'; // Only if $page_id !== '2 || 8'
} else if ("$page_id" === '5' || "$page_id" === '6' || "$page_id" === '7') {
    $path = '../images/'; // Only if $page_id == '5-7'
} else {
    $path = '/images/'; // For everything else
}
```

But actually, the last else says *'For everything else'*, though because of the inequality in the first condition (`!`) the first one feels like everything else. So it would better be rewritten as follows (paths are swapped):

```
if ("$page_id" === '2' || "$page_id" === '8'){
    $path = '/images/'; // Only if $page_id === '2 || 8'
} else if ("$page_id" === '5' || "$page_id" === '6' || "$page_id" === '7') {
    $path = '../images/'; // Only if $page_id == '5-7'
} else {
    $path = './images/'; // For everything else
}
```

That also solves a bug, because as Nitigya Kuchhal correctly mentioned in the comments, the second branch will never be executed, because for instance 5 will also be not 2 or 8, so in that case it would enter -incorrectly- the first branch of the if.

And finally, some might find a `switch` statement more readable than an if else tree like that. It uses more lines, but as you can see, you can read it more easily and it is pretty much self-documenting. Switch isn't strict, though, but I guess that won't be a problem in this case.

Also note that the bug that existed in the original code (you would never get 5,6 or 7) is fixed, and there is actually no way to do it wrong now, except when you forget `break` :).

```
switch ($page_id)
{
  case '2':
  case '8':
    $path = '/images/';
    break;
  case '5':
  case '6':
  case '7':
    $path = '../images/';
    break;
  default:
    $path = './images/';
    break;
}
```

Comment: will second condition be ever true. if page_id is 5, first condition itself will be true.

Comment: This seems to be the answer. Perhaps I'll look for a better way to work with these variables though...

Comment: Yeah this last edit did the trick. Thanks. I'll accept this as answer as soon as SO lets me to do so.